# Which CSS pseudo-classes don't have specificity?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-specificity

I'm studying a bit of CSS and from reading there are some pseudo-classes that don't have specificity like `where()` and `not()`. Are there more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the specification you can find the full detail of specificity calculation. I am going to refer to [CSS selectors level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#specificity-rules) that include all the new selectors:

> A selector’s specificity is calculated for a given element as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= A)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= B)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= C)
> - **ignore the universal selector**
>
> If the selector is a selector list, this number is calculated for each selector in the list. For a given matching process against the list, the specificity in effect is that of the most specific selector in the list that matches.
>
> A few pseudo-classes provide “evaluation contexts” for other selectors, and so have their specificity defined specially:
>
> The specificity of an `:is()`, `:not()`, or `:has()` pseudo-class **is replaced by the specificity of the most specific complex selector in its selector list argument**.
>
> Analogously, the specificity of an `:nth-child()` or `:nth-last-child()` selector is the specificity of the pseudo class itself (counting as one pseudo-class selector) plus the specificity of the most specific complex selector in its selector list argument (if any).
>
> The specificity of a `:where()` pseudo-class is replaced by zero.

So basically, the `*` never counts and it's the same for `:where()`. You can also read that:

> neither the `:where` pseudo-class, nor any of its arguments contribute to the specificity of the selector—its specificity is always zero. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#zero-matches)</sup>

For `:is()`, `:not()` and `:has()` you consider what is inside. This means that the following selector have the same speficity:

```
a:not(.class) == a.class
a:not(#id):is(.class) == a#id.class
```

But pay attention to the sentence: *is replaced by the specificity of the most specific complex selector in its selector list argument*. In the near future we can write something like :

```
a:not(.class, #id)
```

and its specificity is equal to

```
a#id
```

and not to

```
a.class#id
```

---

Considering this, only `:where()` doesn't have any specificity or, to use better words, doesn't contribute to the specificity calculation. `:not()`, `:is()` and `:has()` do but **only** based on what they have inside, unlike `:nth-child()` where we count it in the B and we also count what it contains.

Note that in the future we can write something like below:

```
 a:nth-child(-n+3 of li.important)
```

Which have a specificty equal to 1 class selector (`.important`) + 1 pseudo class (`:nth-child`) + 2 type selector (`a` `li`)

Comment: are we able to use ```:is()``` and ```:has()``` ? I was trying to use them but it wasent for me.

Comment: @ghost2092000 they still have no support yet, you cannot use them. I considered the new Specification that detail the actual and the future selector to make the answer generic but actually you only have the `:not()` selector that you can use

Comment: What's up with `:host`'s specificity?

Comment: @Mendy https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector : *The specificity of :host is that of a pseudo-class. The specificity of :host() is that of a pseudo-class, plus the specificity of its argument.*