# CSS: Target an element that has none of a list of classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to create a rule for certain elements which **only affects an element if it has *none* of a list of classes**.

My attempt:

```css
div:not(.a, .c) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

If you run this snippet, it obviously does not work as intended. Seems the selector is invalid and does not affect any `div` whatsoever.

Next I tried chaining `:not()` which seems very clumsy, but works:

```css
div:not(.a):not(.c) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

Is this the only way to solve the given problem?

Comment: Selector lists are only supported by Safari, so yes, chaining is the only way to do it currently. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class or attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class-or-attr)

Comment: @T04435 Obviously it does not.

Comment: Are you on plain css or you got a preprocessor scss, less ...?

Comment: @T04435 Plain CSS.

Comment: @Turnip If you add that as an answer, I'll pick it.

Comment: you should note that both selectors will select the same elements (even if the first one is still not supported and will be released in the Level 4: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#selector-list) but they will not have the same specificity, the last one is more specific than the first (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364095/8620333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining the `:not()` selector in CSS is the only way at present (in Jan 2020) to indicate a logical **AND** operator.

So, yes:

```
div:not(.a):not(.c)
```

is the correct way to write:

`div:not(.a)` **AND** `div:not(.c)`

```css
div:not(.a):not(.c) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think by your question you always know the classes you don't want to change the styles for. So assuming that this is my take at it.

```css
.all {
  /** give default styles to all elements */
  color: red;
}

.a,
.c {
  /** then reset the ones you where targeting with :not():not()... */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="all a">a</div>
<div class="all b">b</div>
<div class="all c">c</div>
```

Comment: I suspect that this is exactly what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Exactly. I have a much more complex scenario where I need this, and by all means want to avoid specificity war.