# CSS without using !important and follow DRY principal

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic5

I do not like to use `!important` on CSS. But unfortunately I have a situation where I cannot ignore it. Do you know how to overcome such situations?

e.g. I need to use this on a number of Ionic pages.

```
.font-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If I'll use this on each and every page then I do not need `!important`. But the above kind of code violates DRY principal.

To follow DRY I can do this:

`global.scss`

```
 .font-bold {
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
```

So how Can I follow DRY and without using `!important` on the Ionic 5 app?

Comment: Make the css rule more specific maybe. What's taking precedence without the !important?

Comment: @David Then it tightly coupled with the UI layout no? I would like to use above code just like utility method.

Comment: maybe something like this `.font-bold:not(#random) {
    font-weight: bold;
}` ? you increase the specificity with an ID selector

Comment: Then add your rule  in another scss file and import it in your components? But I'd like to know what happens if you don't use the !important... what's taking precedence?

Comment: @TemaniAfif ID selector will not work here since the `global.scss` file is a Root file and pages are in too deep to the folder structure. And reusability is very less when we use IDs. Do you know how utility libraries do this job? Do they use  `!important`?

Comment: @David It has this on the page level `.sc-ion-label-md-s h2 {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}` All are default due to Ionic components and etc. I didn't give any of these.

Comment: yes all of them use !important .. and you don't need to add an ID, I used a trick with not() to increase the specificity of the selector, try and see.

Comment: in bootstrap you will find around 1000 important: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh `1042` :D It gave me some relief to me. Thanks.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I didn't get your trick here `.font-bold:not(#random) { font-weight: bold; }` What is `#random` Could I have an example of usage this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/on50e1sb/ : random is simply a *random* string ;)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633333/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364095/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh.. It is working. Is this good practice or not? I hope you could put this as an answer here too. Thanks.

Comment: I would say it's a bit hacky but if something is working then it's a good practise for me. By the way, important is the logical way to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the use of `!important`<sup>1</sup> but you can always try to increase the specificity of the selector to make sur it will always win.

One idea is to consider ID which has the highest specificity that you combine with the `:not()` selector. Simply make sure to use a random ID that will never be used:

```css
.font-bold:not(#randomID) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box p {
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>some text here</p>

</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="font-bold">some text here</p>
</div>
```

More detail here: [Which CSS pseudo-classes don't have specificity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59362436/8620333)

---

<sup>1</sup>: Boostrap uses around 1000 `!important` (https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Stack Overflow uses around 2970 `!important` too (https://stackoverflow.com/Content/Shared/stacks.css)